# AI Civ having another civ's specialty unit

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

How is it possible for an AI civilization to gain/build another civilization's specialty unit?

Twice now I have run into this issue.  On my current game, the Dutch have a Cho-Ko-Nu (the chinese specialty unit).  In a prior game, the Swiss had Legion units (the Roman spec. unit).

Answer (score 17):

In Gods and Kings, *Militaristic* City-States can sometimes grant the Unique Units of civilizations that are not in the current game as their unit gifts. Each Militaristic City-State grants a different UU, which can be found from that City-State's interaction screen.

Likely, the AI Civ in question made friends/allies with a nearby Militaristic CS, which is now granting them Cho-Ko-Nu.

Comment: This has been true since before Gods and Kings - especially in the case of city states gifting Great People when you have the Patronage social policy, where Mongolia's special unit the Great Khan (replacement of the Great General) can be gifted with the same chance as other Great people

Comment: @AliceRees Ah, okay. It has been so long since playing without G&K that I did not remember if it was new to G&K or was always the case, so I prefaced my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this answer.  It was really bugging me, because I thought my game was glitched.

Comment: @Allen You're quite welcome! If it's solved your problem, it's customary to click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that you've accepted this answer as correct and that it solved your issue. It gives both of us reputation here on Arqade if you do so! :)

Comment: @AliceRees - Interesting, I had never seen this happen pre-G&K but saw it several times in my first few G&K games. I assumed it was new in G&K.