# How do City State unit gifts work?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Earlier in the game, I received a few units from allied CS Valetta. The odd part is that these units were H'wachas, a Korea only unit. There was no Korea in this game to gift it to them either. How does this work, and how did it happen?

Comment: Closely related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83225/ai-civ-having-another-civs-specialty-unit

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, the linked question doesn't ask about city states giving the player units, it asks about other civs having unique units. Having the same answer doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Comment: @shanodin agreed, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, but worth linking them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

City states can gift any unit, including unique units (of civilizations not in the current game). For instance, if you have the patronage policy resulting in occasional Great People gifts, you might be given Khans.

From the [Civ5 Wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/City-state_%28Civ5%29):

> Militaristic City-states have also been updated in Gods and Kings,
>   giving them ability to gift you unique units from other civilizations
>   (for example, the Chu-Ko-Nu, a Chinese unique unit).

You can see which militaristic city state can give what unique unit in that CS's diplomacy screen.

Comment: They were also capturing barbarians.

Comment: What? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You should clarify that each military city state gives one specific UU, which you can see by hovering over the time remaining thing in the city state menu. It says something like "This citystate knows the secrets of the Hwacha and will share it with you if you have the technology 'engineering'. That may be new to BNW though

Comment: I don't have BNW

Comment: @shanodin He is probably thinking that, well say there is a unit specific to Korea. Barbarians attacked Korea and stole that civilization-specific unit. The City-State then killed those barbarians, and took the unit for themselves.

Comment: @avestar101 You can't capture military units, you can only capture civilians (workers, settlers etc)